# HTML/CSS Background transparency

Tags: html, css, web, alphablending, alpha-transparency

Is there a way for the white backdrop of my web site to be completely see-through? I tried using rgba but it doesn't give me the result I desire. Any input leading to a solution to my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is hard to know what you are asking here- do you mean that you want the background of your _browser_ to be see-through, so that you can see your desktop underneath it?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completly see-through? 
You can use the css:

```
selector
{
   background: transparent;
}
```

But you might also want to set the background to `none;`, but i'm not sure where this is exactly for.

---

If you mean the browsers background itself. No that's not possible. It will only be possible if you modifie the client, but that will still be offline(unless others download the same client). So short answer; **No, that's not possible.**

Comment: here is what I got:

<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   selector
   {
    background: transparent;
   }
  </style>
  <title>
   My App
  </title>
 </head>
<center>
 <h1>Background Survey</h1>
</center>
</html>

Comment: the selector in my css is a place holder of your element, class or id name. **[More info here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**. Btw, read my update, you can't have a transparent browser background.

Comment: can you please elaborate I lost you at element

Comment: I suggest you to read the basics about HTML first :) Do not rush to learn, start with the basics first. But **It's not possible** what you are trying to do :) Would be cool hehe.

Comment: I know the basics I just thought what I wanted lies in the advanced. But thanks anyways.